# fixing doubly encoded UTF-8 files

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

So I have this doubly encoded UTF-8 file. eg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>this is a Ã¢â‚¬Å“testÃ¢â‚¬Â</p>
</body>
</html>
```

URL: http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/utf8-1.html

If, in Firefox, I view the source and then copy / paste it into a new file I've effectively undone the double encoding. eg.

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/utf8-2.html

My question is... how can I do this via the CLI?

I tried this:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 utf8-1.html > utf8-3.html
```

But got this:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 294
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try `Windows-1252` instead of `ISO-8859-1`.

This is the difference between Windows Latin-1, and Latin-1. All browsers, also Mac and Linux, wrongly accept as ISO-8859-1 the Windows-Latin-1, as that fills in the 0x80-0x9F characters.

No guarantee that everything is resolved though.

Comment: @dan04 right, it is just [lying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252); HTML5 mentioned - ;).

Comment: By the way, the used quotes in the text, are in the range 0x80 - 0x9F.